# How can we change a wx.MenuBar background and foreground colour using wxpython?

Tags: python, wxpython

I want to change the wxpython menubar colours.

How can I do it?

Comment: Is there overdraft protection on reputation?  You have three 100 reputation bounties outstanding but only 161 reputation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways

1. Hard way , write your own custom menu bar from PyControl, position it at top of window, and create popup windows for submenus.
2. Easier way: you can use win32api to change system menu colors for your app. Here is an example showing that http://code.activestate.com/recipes/440507-changing-the-background-color-of-the-menu-bar-in-a/

Answer (score -1):

don't think it's doable -- it defaults to the platform's native look